# Regex first column header csv

Tags: regex, csv

What would the regex be for matching the first column header in a csv file?

```
id,field1,field2
1,n/a,n/a
2,n/a,n/a
...
```

I just safely want to match `id`

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Regex can be different depending on flavour.

Comment: @Toto the java 8 version, so the accepted answer would then be "^([^,]*)"g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([^,]*)/g
```

If you want to test on https://regex101.com/

- ^ = start at the beginning of the string
- [^,] = match anything except a comma
- ([^,]*) = get everything from the beginning of the string to the comma
- /g = don't return after first match